# CSS: table border separated horizontally and collapsed vertically

Tags: html, css

is there any way to apply to a table cells' both the separate and the collapsed border properties to have  collapsed but  separated? Thanks

**EDIT**: this is the wanted result:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the `border-collapse` does not allow for separate defining of the horizontal and vertical. You can achieve it with extra markup (which, on a table, could end up being **a lot** of extra markup), so *I don't advise it,* but I will give the code for it:

Html:

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <th><div>Header 1</div></th>
     <th><div>Header 2</div></th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><div>Content 1</div></td>
     <td><div>Content 2</div></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><div>Content 3</div></td>
     <td><div>Content 4</div></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

And css:

```
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
th, td { border: 0; padding: 0;}
th div, td div {margin: 5px 0 0; border: 1px solid #ff0000; padding: 5px;}
```

Of course, you may want to use a class on the `div` or a child selector, some way of only targeting the `div` if you might have other div's in the `table` data. The `margin` controls your horizontal gap, and of course, your `padding` or `border` width can be whatever you want.

Comment: With a th div, td div {margin: -1px 5px 0; border: 1px solid #ff0000; padding: 5px;}​ you get what you want : http://jsfiddle.net/7h5rV/

Comment: That would give him the opposite of what he wants, it would separate the verticals and collapse the horizontals. However, your `-1px` margin is a good point, as my solution would put a double border on the vertical, so he will need to deal with that somehow, whether through negative margin or only putting border on left except the last cell in a row.

Answer (score 25):

Perhaps

```
table {
  border-spacing: 1px 0;
}
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer.

Comment: Had to make sure to add 'border-collapse: separate;' in my case as, by default in my css, they are collapsed.

Answer (score 6):

The closest I can get is:

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 4px 0;
}
table td, table th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Unfortunately, this will create a double-thick line between the rows. Negative values are not allowed in the `border-spacing` property, otherwise `-1px` would probably work.

---

You could make the other lines 2px wide if that is acceptable, then at least you wouldn't have differing border thicknesses:

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 4px 0;
}
table td, table th {
    border-width: 1px 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
}
table tr:first-child th,
table tr:first-child td {
    border-top-width: 2px;
}
table tr:last-child th,
table tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Another alternative is to set the border-bottom of the top row to 0

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved without using extra div elements in the th & td cells. This solution works in Chrome, Firefox and IE8+.

**CSS**

```
table
{
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 10px 0px;
}
td, th
{
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-top: none;
}
table tr:first-child th
{
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Change **table tr:first-child th** to **table tr:first-child td** if the table's first row doesn't contain table header cells (TH).

See my jsfiddle here: [Table with column spacing but collapsed row border](http://jsfiddle.net/ben1/o31u0w9q/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table td {
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 3px;  
}
```

It doesn't use the `border-collapse` property, but it creates an outer table border with each `<td>` in its own separate border.